# how to store the multi dimensional array and fetch using sqflite in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the multi dimensional array and i want to store it in the sqflite db. I need to fetch based on the date from that.Please advise how to store it and fetch.

```dart
[{
    "Date": "2020-02-17",
    "Data": [{
       "Id": 1
    }, {
        "Id": 2
    }, {
        "Id": 3
    }]
},
 {
    "Date": "2020-02-18",
    "Data": [{
       "Id": 4
    }, {
        "Id": 5
    }, {
        "Id": 6
    }]
}]
```

Comment: You need two tables, one to store the date values and the other to store the mapped values

Comment: there are tons of tutorials available on the web